# Get lastest version of a content group SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, zend-db-table

I have content table where I have many contents and various versions of those contents.
The columns are `content varchar`,`document_id int` (identifies a content between many versions) and version int

I want to return the lastest version of each content group. I tried using this SQL but it returns me just the first version but I want the last.The order by doesn't work with group by.

```
SELECT * FROM content where id_project = 8 group by document_id order by version desc;
```

How can i get the lastest version of all unique content(unique content is identified by the document_id)?

Thanks if anyone can help me

Comment: do you want the latest content or the latest version number?

Comment: @lmre-l I want the lastest content version but your sql seems working fine! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.* FROM content c1
  left join content c2 on c1.document_id = c2.document_id and c1.version < c2.version
 where c2.document_id is null
   and c1.id_project = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT document_id,MAX(version) FROM content WHERE id_project = 8 GROUP BY document_id`

Comment: it informs me what is the lastest version but don't bring me the row which has the lastest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like

```
SELECT *
FROM content A
WHERE version = (
    SELECT MAX(version)
    FROM content B
    WHERE B.document_id = A.document_id
)
AND document_id = 8
```

Assuming each set of versions is "grouped" by a `document_id`.